# MongoDB Match 2 criteria

Tags: mongodb

Given the Set in my Image Example,
Is it possible to retrieve by ID and if 'element is in the array'?

As you can see I can find all the records with the element in the array, but as I drill down and find the one by ID as well, it throws an Error, I suspect my syntax is wrong

---

here is a link to my chat on SO https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5006697#5006697

Thanks in Advance

- CAM
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have the `$in` in the projection field (what you want to return) because you closed out the criteria document (what you want to find) early.  Try this:

```
db.users.find( {'_id':1, 'companies-visited': { $in:["stocktwits"]}})
```